# deploying spring mvc project in open shift

Tags: spring, git, maven, spring-mvc, openshift

Hello everyone I'm new with open shift and GIT and I try to depoly my spring mvc project on open shift and I get errors I can't manage to resolve them to deploy the application.

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.5.1: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:pom:2.5.1 in http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of eap has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)
Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control build' for /var/lib/openshift/5674c0e22d5271dc8d000016/jbossews
```

POM.XML

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>GestionBP</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
                            <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </build>
```

Can someone help me. Thank you aa lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the forced version number?